# Pulling html text from Message Catalog via Peoplecode

Tags: html, peoplesoft

I am using Peoplecode to try and pull text from a message catalog.  This is the text it is pulling:  Significantly
Exceeds\nExpectations

I want there to be a line break after Significantly and a line break after Exceeds.  As you can see I am trying two different things. 
 and \n

Here is the PEoplecode I plug it into:

```
&sReviewMsgs = &sReviewMsgs | "<div id='act_grph_review_msg_5'>" | MsgGetText(25001, 47, "Message Not Found: Significantly Exceeds Expectations.") | "</div>";
```

Unfortunatley, it doesn't pick up the line breaks and it just displays this text on the webpage:  Significantly
Exceeds\nExpectations

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line break with a `<br />`.